How does a thin-film transistor (TFT) work?
From all sources I could find online and in my university lecture, TFT's are essentially just like MOSFETs but thin.


But I noticed that every detailed MOSFET diagram shows an n-type semiconductor area under the drain and source contacts, and the bulk material is p-type doped. The conductive channel is created by the carriers from the aforementioned n-type area. The substrate is also shown to be connected to the source. In every TFT diagram I've seen, there hasn't been any different-doped areas, diagrams only mention the material name. I also haven't found any paper that explains this. Most papers I found on TFT construction only mention the semiconductor deposition method, like spin coating or vapor deposition. So do TFTs have those different-doped areas like MOSFETs, or do they work in a different way?
Image sources:
https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/tran_6.html
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxide_thin-film_transistor

For suitable types of semiconductor, and doping levels, simply applying an electric field to the surface either draws charge carriers closer, or repels them away; either way, the conductivity can be modulated, from a low point inbetween (depleted) to electron conduction (enhancement N-channel) or holes (inversion) (or vice-versa for P-channel).
This effect is common enough, it can even be hacked to work with seemingly unrelated materials or devices: FET Transistor Homemade From Cadmium Sulfide Photocell | sparkbangbuzz.com
A substrate is not required.  The main reason a substrate is used, in monocrystalline semiconductor fabrication, is because it provides the crystal orientation for the transistors, maximizing charge-carrier mobility, and perhaps providing a source for free charge carriers (particularly as modern transistors are so small, they might not have any dopant atoms in them at all).  Indeed, Si on sapphire (SoS), and SOI (silicon on insulator), are processes that have been used, and are in regular use, to replace or remove the substrate, reducing capacitance and conferring radiation immunity (SOI is commonly used in spacecraft).
A substrate connection can be useful, but isn't generally obligatory.  In discrete transistors, it was referred to as the "back gate", as biasing the substrate (independent of drain and source) has a similar effect to biasing the gate: field-induced channel formation is influenced.  This might also be used in analog ICs (when a free "well" can be connected, as opposed to FETs made right in the substrate itself).
Note that, in the above examples, doping (along the channel) isn't strictly required: if the semiconductor is thin enough, its entire bulk (this might be a few 100 nm thick) can become depleted and thus nonconductive by the applied field, or perhaps double the thickness if a wrap-around gate is used (thus influencing both sides of the semiconductor layer).  Doping varies the ("on" and "off") conductivity, polarity, and gate threshold voltage.
As for TFTs, the (Wikipedia) reference provides some explanation:

One significant drawback with oxide TFTs is that there are very few p-type (hole transporting) metal oxide semiconductors.

Metal oxides such as ZnO are often non-stoichiometric, i.e. in this case, lacking some oxygen atoms, making it N-doped naturally.  This is fine for (induced) P-channel transistors, or (enhanced) N-channel, but makes general-purpose semiconductor fabrication challenging: diodes, BJTs, complementary MOS, etc. are ruled out.  Likewise, there is no body diode effect, or "back gate", because there's literally no substrate providing such junctions, or bias.

Some device physics textbooks do address the operation of TFTs. OP will have to look around.
It is easiest to understand a TFT with doped contacts. Suppose the contacts are n+. When a positive voltage is applied to the gate, initially compensating charge comes from changing the charge state of traps inside the band gap. If this does not provide enough compensating charge, there will be (immediately after application of the gate voltage) an electric field from gate to the S-D contacts that causes electrons to flow to provide a channel.
By the way, the drawing is a bit confusing because the semiconductor is labeled a metal oxide semiconductor, which (1) is not universally the case (some TFTs have amorphous or polysilicon channels) and (2) tends to confuse the semiconductor material with the metal oxide semiconductor structure found in all TFTs.
